# Checking if query string exist in Logic App HTTP Request

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-logic-apps

How do i check if a query string exist in a Logic App HTTP Request? I know how to get the value if it exist `triggerOutputs()['queries']['name']` but not sure how to check if its null as the parameter is optional

Comment: `triggerOutputs()?['queries']?['name']` should work

Answer (score 5):

You have to use ? operator, for example:

```
trigger().outputs?.queries?.name
```

Also, you can use **coalesce** if you want to get other value, if name is null:

```
@coalesce(trigger().outputs?.queries?.name, 'my t value instead of name')
```